# How to redirect to a URL in a google extension content script and wait before continuing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a google chrome extension with a content script that:

1. Parses the current page's HTML and does some logic around that
2. redirects to a url by sending a message to a background worker
3. do some more logic based off the new url's HTML when a response is received

When step 3 executes the redirect has not finished loading yet. So the HTML that gets parsed is from the old url, not the new one.

Below is my code:

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: url}, response => {
   jobs = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('p'), function(e) {
      return e.outerHTML;
   }).join();
   alert(location.href);
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect}, function(tab) {
                sendResponse({response: 'loaded'});
        });

        return true; //make this asynchronous so that we can send a response through the callback
});
```

When I run this code I get a popup with the previous URL, and once I click ok on that alert the redirect finishes loading and then I see the new page. How can I fix this so that the redirect finishes loading before the sendResponse is sent?

I tried moving some code around between the background worker and context worker but I believe the code is where it is supposed to be. The DOM needs to be interacted with so the context worker needs to have a majority of the code.